# How can I convert timstamp to a readable time?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timestamp

How can I convert `2016-12-20T18:36:14.000Z` to a readable date/time in PHP?

like `Dec 20, 2016`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DateTime::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) like this:

```
<?php
echo  date_create('2016-12-20T18:36:14.000Z')->format('M d, Y');
```

output:

```
~$ php test.php
Dec 20, 2016l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$olddate = '2016-12-20T18:36:14.000Z';
echo date('M d,Y',strtotime($olddate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date('mdY') == date('mdY', strtotime($timestamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following will do the trick

```
$t = "2016-12-20T18:36:14.000Z";
echo date('M d,Y', strtotime($t));
```